# Use Visual Studio web server in local network

Tags: visual-studio, webserver

Is there a way to access visual studio web server from another computer that share the same router? I tried connecting to the IP address but it didnt work. Is there a setting in VS? or firewall?

Comment: The Visual Studio server uses dynamic ports, so when you start debugging the web app get's a random port number and not the standard http (80) port. You need to access using a url like: `http://dev.machine.ip.address:xxxx/` where xxxx is the port number assigned to your application.

Comment: @Xint0, port number can be fixed via project settings to any desired number.

Comment: @afsharm you're right, but by default it gets a random port number above 1024

Comment: cant' be done. just put it on IIS, doesn't take long.

Comment: But I won't be able to debug the code in IIS? I want to step through each line of a method.

Answer (score 14):

You can achieve this by installing IIS Express.
Go to

> http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1038

Once installed, change your project setting to this:
[image: Project Settings]

Then go to

> %userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config

and for the project change the binding to this:

```
   <bindings>
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":54715:" />
   </bindings>
```

Note, you can also specify the bindings like this if you just want to limit it to your IP and machine name:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:54715:localhost" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:54715:anishaalaptop" />
```

I debug my app over Wifi using my android app so I leave the binding open.

Comment: I get "Bad Request (Invalid Hostname)". Any ideas?

Comment: Check your firewall.  Also make sure your binding is specified with an asterisk.

<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:54715:localhost" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:54715:anishaalaptop" />

Comment: I get an access denied error when attempting to bind to anything other than localhost. Are you running VS as Admin?

Comment: @MicroSoft, why make use jump thru so many stupid hoops just to do something so simple?!? Unfortunately there seems to be a Microsoft department whose job it is to dream up how hard MS can make some of the simplest tasks for us programmers! This is but one of a myriad of examples of such. Okay. I'm done with my rant now. ;P

Answer (score 9):

I assume you mean the cassini web server built into visual studio. In short, no you can't. That cassini web server can only be accessed from the local computer.

I found some further information. According to MSDN, you can't access it from another machine. What are some known functionality limitations of the Cassini Web server?

It can host only one ASP.NET application per port.
It does not support HTTPS.
It does not support authentication.
It responds only to localhost requests.

see this MSDN article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893391

Answer (score 4):

You can use ngrok or an extension for VS https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti . I'm using this extension and it's very useful [image]