# How do I launch IIS 7.5 Express?

Tags: iis-express

We have a new employee who has to work on an old ASP web site.

Our IT people did not install IIS on her Windows XP machine so I tried to do it myself, but I need the Windows CD and I don't have it.

So, I downloaded and installed IIS 7.5 Express because I thought it as a lightweight IIS, but I can't figure how to run it, it even doesn't show up in Administration Tools or anywhere else.

Comment: I answered a similar question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11941018/463469

Answer (score 18):

Option-1:

1. Start command prompt
2. Goto "%programfiles%\IIS Express"
   IIS Express gets installed in to "%programfiles%\IIS Express" (in case x64-bit OS, "%programfiles(x86)\IIS Express").
3. run "iisexpress.exe". This will setup a default web site 'WebSite1' and starts it up.
4. In sys tray you can see running IIS Express instaces

Note: IIS Express configuration files are located in "%userprofile%\my documents\iisexpress\config"

Option-2:
Use WebMatrix which has functionality like start/stop/restart IIS Express and editing few IIS Express settings. Download links:

- [Latest version](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) (Windows 8 or Windows 7 only)
- [WebMatrix 2](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/v2/) (Vista and below)