# Installing IIS on Windows 7 Home Basic

Tags: windows, iis, windows-7, iis-express, webmatrix

I have a ASP.NET application and I would like to deploy it on a webserver.
So I searched for a some tutorials and most of them tell to enable the IIS Management Console in control panel.But I don't have such an entry in there.

[image: No Entry]

So I guessed that I have some component missing(jigsaw) and used the MS WebPI utility to install IIS components and other things even remotely connected to web development.
I have installed
   Web deploy 3.0
   IIS Express 7.5 
  .NET framework 4 
   and MS web tools for Visual studio 2010.

[image]
Still no luck.Run>inetmgr still fails.There is no inetpub folder anywhere.(I expected something like apache htdocs folder)

Excuse me for the newbie question.I am in windows7 home basic.

Comment: Have you tried to check the official website of IIS? http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7

Comment: Yes I have checked that.It tells to use the webPI which as I have mentioned already used without luck.And the second option is for window feature on or off which unfortunately is not visible.

Comment: So, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469058/how-do-i-launch-iis-7-5-express. Looks like you'd want to install WebMatrix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are NOT able to use full-fledged IIS with Windows 7 Home Basic.

[According to MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753473.aspx) IIS7 installed on Windows 7 Home Basic is too limited and you won't be able to run ASP.Net application there. IIS Management Console is also unavailable on Windows 7 Home Basic.

I think that you can try IIS Express and all-in-one [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) solution. WebMatrix provides you with a neat interface to start /stop / restart IIS Express and to edit some of IIS Express settings.

Comment: Thanks a lot.The webMatrix solution is pretty good and works like a breeze.