# EntityFramework.dll failed to copy to web server using FileZilla

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, filezilla

while hosting .NET MVC Web Project in somee.com, i get below error in FileZilla Client, i am trying to copy EntityFramework.dll and EntityFramework.xml files to my project bin folder in web server, hosting first time , Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

> Error Shown in File Zilla Client :
>
> Command:  STOR EntityFramework.dll
>
> Response: 550 The process cannot access the file because it is being
>   used by another process.
>
> Error:    Critical file transfer error
>
> Status:   Disconnected from server
>
> Command:  STOR EntityFramework.xml
>
> Response: 550 The process cannot access the file because it is being
>   used by another  process.
>
> Error:    Critical file transfer error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally arrived to solution, i tried stop IIS from command prompt, but this [Installing IIS on Windows 7 Home Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248427/installing-iis-on-windows-7-home-basic) research proved that windows 7 home basic doesn't allow install of full-fledged IIS,

Then even if i try to  install the IIS from Turn Windows Features on Off, i get this error : "  Not all of the features were successfully changed "  so i unchecked IIS, Internet Information Services Hostable Web Core and Windows Process Activation Service then restarted the machine,

At Last Instead of using FileZilla to Transfer the Dll and Xml files, i came across Windows Publishing Wizard, located in Program Files/Web Publish. provided the host name  etc, dll was successful transferred but xml file gave the same error again, so as i read in some asp.net forums, i removed the referenced EntityFramework.dll from closed project, using project properties --> References --> Unused References , then XML file was also done.

I provided whole details because it may help someone there.

Thank you, @Vsevolod and @Kami.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your solution is working when you're trying to copy the assemblies. Stop your server and then copy the dlls as they are used by the application

Comment: @Vswvolod , no my solution is not opened , actually i did this project in VS 2013 in another machine, i am just trying to upload the project folders from my current Machine to somee.com , its a free asp.net hosting provider.

Comment: @stom make sure that these dlls are not used in any running solution or project

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly enough, the file is in use and cannot be copied.

The IIS process is likely using the file to access database resources or running website queries.  As such you need to shut-down IIS temporarily to copy the file.  Once the copy is successful, you can then start IIS back again.

This assumes that the file needs to be copied.  If the file is the same, and not changed in any way, you can ignore the error as a copy is not needed.

Comment: ,i just installed .net framework, 4.5 two days back, then i tried to start IIS but it failed with this error : not all of the features were successfully changed, so IIS is not started anyway, i am using VS 2010.

Comment: @stom There may be some other process that is using or locking the file or it may be a bad install.  Ensure nothing else is running, or try a reboot to shut-down process that you are not able to identify.