# How do you publish an ASP.net MVC application from Visual Studio 2013 to your local network?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications, visual-studio-2013, localhost, lan

I made a simple ASP.net MVC web application in Visual Studio 2013, and I want to deploy it so it can be accessed from the browser on other computers on my local network. I have tried right-clicking my project > Publish (not sure what settings to use, Web Deploy, Web deploy package, File system, 
I published the website to my inetpub/wwwroot folder.

I managed to get IIS up an running, I've tried adding an application in the manager and editing the permissions to Everyone. I tried navigating to localhost/application_name but I was getting errors about not being configured to list the directory. I enabled directory browsing, but that just means it now shows a list of the files. How do I get it to actually run the app when I navigate to it in the browser? 
Am I close?

Edit: currently trying this http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Accessing-an-IIS-Express-site-from-a-remote-computer  (although this I think is a step or two ahead of where I am)
Also tried this: http://www.programmerfish.com/how-to-deploy-asp-net-web-application-on-the-network-in-windows-7/#.VGTLCvnF81L no luck so far

Comment: I am not versed on latest VS versions but afik VS only allows to access the embedded web server from localhosts (probably restricted indeed). I'd bet you need to install IIS locally

Comment: What does that mean? I think IIS is installed locally.

Comment: As far as I remember the one that comes with VS is just for debugging purposes and so restricted. You need to install a complete version

Comment: Yea, I'm pretty sure it's installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that ASP.net was not registered with IIS

1. Opened command prompt as administrator
2. Navigated to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
3. Ran `aspnet_regiis -iru`

Now web app runs in IIS http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-server-environments-for-web-deployment/configuring-a-web-server-for-web-deploy-publishing-%28remote-agent%29

Answer (score 4):

You can use IIS Express which comes with visual studio 2013. I've used this method to allow other members of the staff to access the website that is in my computer. Scott Hanselman has done a great post which I use every time when I want to expose a website hosted in local iis express to others in the same network.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx

If you have any queries, let me know. Hope this helps

[image]

Comment: I tried that. I couldn't get it to work. Also that post is about SSL and Visual Studio 2010. I'm using 2013, and the menu options are different. I think it uses IIS Express by default now.

Comment: what was the problem? the IIS Express server must be running in order for this to work (The IIS Express icon must appear in the task bar notification area). I use 2013 too, and it works the same. the only thing you do in VS is hitting that `USE IIS Express`. `1. GETTING IIS EXPRESS TO SERVE EXTERNALLY OVER PORT 80` answers your question

Comment: Where do you see "Use IIS Express"? How do you make sure it's running?

Comment: right click on your `project` (not the solution), go to properties. now from the options in the left, select web. Under Servers, there is a dropdown. if IIS Express is already selected, then you are using IIS Express already. otherwise, select IIS Express and save

Comment: Yea, it's using IIS Express. So if I want to get the app to run I have to start debugging from Visual Studio every time?

Comment: Yes, you have to have your visual studio opened up with the project. It doesn't need to be in debug mode, you just have to run it one time for the IIS Express to start. if IIS Express icon disappear when you stop the application from debug mode, this can be fixed by going to the settings page I mentioned above and just under Servers, there is another section called Debuggers. Under that, you will see `Enable Edit and Continue` just untick that and run the application one more time. Now, stopping debugging doesn't shutdown your IIS Express server. But it will close if you close VS.

Comment: OK; And if I add my IP address to the applicationhost.config file bindings, then can I run the app on other devices?

Comment: I haven't tried with the ip address, but I don't see why it should not work.

Comment: Awesome, yes it worked! This is more of a solution for testing though right? Presumably it'll be better for me to get it working in the long term through the IIS manager...

Comment: yes, I wouldn't run a production app on my machine and certainly not through IIS Express. This is for testing and it is useful to have when you want someone to test the functionality of your app before going to production and that the person doesn't have VS to run the app

Answer (score 2):

When I want to use IIS Express within Visual Studio for development, but allow local network users to see a version of my site, I tend to create a publish profile in VS that publishes to the local file system (e.g. `C:\Publish\<yourwebsite>`). Then from IIS Manager create a new website pointed to that same folder and it should be accessible to you via `http://localhost` and to network users via `http://<your-pc-name>` or `http://<your-local-ip>`.

You will need to add an exception to Windows Firewall to permit HTTP requests (i.e. port 80) through to your local machine, but if you have configured IIS correctly they should see the website.

It is possible to make IIS Express available to remote clients but that's not what it's designed for so really you're better off going down the IIS route since this will allow you to test the configuration as it would be on a live/production setting at the same time.

Comment: I tried that, but that application doesn't run when I navigate to where I published it. It just lists the directory.

Comment: It even works (shows the directory) when I navigate to my IP address on other devices; How do I get it to run the application instead?

Comment: What version of MVC are you targeting? The only reason IIS would list the directory is either you've pointed the site at the wrong folder (it should be the folder with the `bin` directory inside it), or you're missing some IIS component/configuration so it doesn't understand that it's an MVC site. Also what version of IIS are we talking about?

Comment: Also worth checking the Application Pool that your website is running under in IIS and verify it's a .NET 4.0 app pool and not 2.0.

Comment: Using IIS 7. It is pointing to the folder with the bin folder inside of it. MVC version, not sure. How can I check?

Comment: Oh, it was 2.0. Changed it to 4.0. Doesn't seem to have changed.

Comment: Look in the `bin` folder and see if there is a `System.Web.Mvc.dll` file there. If so right-click -> Properties -> Details and check the version number.

Comment: Says 5.2.0  (and then some other stuff I'm guessing doesn't add much here)

Comment: Okay in your Web.config, find (or add) a `<system.webServer>` element and make sure it has `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />` inside it. If there is already a `<modules>` section defined, just add the above attribute to it. See if that makes a difference.

Comment: OK, I added that. Doesn't seem to have made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Check this, and old version of the same question. I'd bet you need to install IIS locally

[Use Visual Studio web server in local network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965511/use-visual-studio-web-server-in-local-network)

Comment: I'm pretty sure IIS is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable IIS on the host as IIS Express is not built with that in mind. Its for debugging purposes.

You've also not mentioned your binding configurations or your app pool settings.

Here is a comprehensive tutorial on how to publish your application using IIS [IIS Video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eU-VVggY_Vs)

You will need to ensure the binding that you specify is available across the network and that the connecting clients have permissions.

Comment: Didn't touch binding configurations. Made a pool using "LocalSystem" should I use something else? I also don't recognize anything in that video. I'm pretty sure IIS is enabled.

Comment: No local system is fine if the LocalSystem has permissions to the application folder. In terms of bindings you have to specify a port in your binding if port 80 is already used (which is automatically created when IIS is installed. Called default web site) what do you see when you browse to localhost?

Comment: A directory listing of the contents of the folder where I published the site. Want it to run the application.

Comment: In the video tutorial he's using Windows 8 and IIS 8, I'm on 7. Do I need this Windows Server Manager?

Comment: @shim I would highly recommend IIS Server Manager. On Windows 7 when you navigate to Add/remove programs then Add/Remove windows components select Internet Information Services. Open run or cmd and type inetmgr. This will open the IIS manager.

Comment: Yes, I am using the IIS Manager

Comment: How do I get my application to run after publishing it to a folder (tried inetpub/wwwroot) using IIS manager?