# Run C# MVC application, in local web server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I've made a C# ASP.NET Application using VS 2013. What I want to do is use it on my localhost using IIS.

How do I do it work? When it go to localhost, it just appears a black page.

I've created a new site on IIS Manager and ponted it to de fisical path of my application. Registered the ASP.NET on IIS...

I've tried whats in the [How do you publish an ASP.net MVC application from Visual Studio 2013 to your local network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26911703/how-do-you-publish-an-asp-net-mvc-application-from-visual-studio-2013-to-your-lo) .

So, I don't need to use IIS, I could use other web server, like Apache...

I want to be able to open Chrome, go to localhost:8080/ for example and get my application, without having to open VS and run the project etc...
Also, if other people could access the application on my local network, it would be great. I just want to use my MVC web aplication like it was on the internet itself, like I can access google.com and use it, but I want to do so in my local network only.

If I try to access a simple HTML file, using IIS, it works perfectly. Now I want to use my C# MVC web application.

Is there a way to do this? Using IIS, Apache, whatever...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please tell us what the specific problem is that you are facing, if there is one.  'How do I run an ASP.NET MVC on local web server?' is too broad a question for this format.  Troubleshoot it, read up on it, try different things until it works.  That's why I'm voting to close this.

Comment: Have you set the binding for your IIS website to localhost or port 8080 if you want to access it on that port?

Comment: the site I've created in IIS Manager, uses the port 5376, and points to inetpub/wwwroot/Test. The Test folder, is the folder where I've published my application with VS using the File System publish method.
So, when I try localhost:5376/ in my browser, nothing happens, just a black page...

Comment: @Luke yes, my bindings are type http, port 5376, IP Address *

Comment: Please open the bindings section, screenshot it and add it to the question.  Also, is the website started?  Click on the website in IIS and click start if not.

Comment: Done. Yes, my site is started, so it is its pool.

If i try to access it like this: localhost:5376/testeMVC/Home, it says that the  resource has been removed, had its name changed or is temporarily unavaliable

Comment: Does your hosts file have a line for `127.0.0.1       localhost`?  Located at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Comment: Have you published the website and deployed the published files, or have you simply copied your source files into that location?

Comment: I've published thru VS. Build -> Publish WebApplication

Comment: hmmm I can't think why this wouldn't work, sounds like everything is in place.