# VS2013 / ASP.NET : how do I connect to my site with an iPad?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm building a site in ASP.NET, and it runs just fine on my computer. Next to my computer are a phone and an iPad. How do I connect to the ASP.NET project being run on my PC from my phone and iPad? I found this software:

http://www.electricplum.com

But that costs money, which I don't want to spend. I have the real devices, so is there a setting I'm missing? How do I broadcast the website in Visual Studio to my entire home network, so it gets an ip in the 192.168.*.** range instead of being confined to localhost?

Comment: Install IIS and bind the site to an IP on the computer. Additionally, you can try using the machine name.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965511/use-visual-studio-web-server-in-local-network